# should link icons be rendered as images or with css background-image url's?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, icons, background-image, image

I want to use iconography in a web UI, while retaining the context language of what clicking on the link will achieve, but possibly not displaying the text and crowding UI space. For example using CRUD screens, I want to display a plus icon for adding an item, a minus icon for deleting, it, a pencil icon for editing it, and a magnifying glass to search for a different item. There are a couple of ways to achieve this.

1. Render an `img` element inside of the `a`nchor. The `img alt` attribute will describe what the icon represents (alt="pencil icon"), and the title attribute will describe the intended consequence (i.e. "Click here to edit this widget").
2. Render an `a`nchor tag only, and use css to display the image as a background. In this case, the anchor's content should describe the intended consequence, however [it needs to be wrapped in a span element so that its display style can be set to none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643529/add-url-link-in-css-background-image). The anchor should also contain a title attribute matching the content (without a surrounding span of course).

It seems to me like option #2 is easier to implement in an asp.net mvc app. Since the icon is a design concern and not a markup concern, it makes sense to define the image in CSS. It also makes things easier from a code maintenance perspective... changing the img src location would only necessitate changes in the CSS file and no view files. Removing the CSS would cause the application to fall back to full text accessibility too.

What smells funny to me is the part about nesting the link content into a span so that it can have `disply: none;` set in the css. Another thing is, if I use the :hover selector to swap the image and provide a rollover / rollout effect, the images seem to take longer to swap out than when done with javascript.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We frequently use option #2, but in a different fashion.  Instead of wrapping the anchor content in a span, use CSS to style the anchor as `display: block` or `inline-block`, then set its `text-indent` to `-1000em` (or similar, just pick a big value).  I think you also have to set `overflow` to `hidden`.

If you do the background image as a sprite (a single image with both the non-hover and hover states in it) and use `:hover` to reposition the background, you should avoid the flicker/delay that you might be seeing now.  That also results in one less separate request hitting your web server.

Note that this also requires explicitly setting the `width` and `height` of the anchor in your CSS to match your icon size.

Comment: Good call on both counts. I didn't think of using text-indent or a sprite, but I'm sure both would be improvements. The a's are already display:inline-block with explicit height & width.

Answer (score 1):

If the icon conveys information that does not duplicate information already in the document, then it should be a real `<img>`.

However, the alt attribute should contain an *alternative* to the image, not a description of it.

```
alt="Edit this widget"
```

The title attribute should only be used to provide advisory information (think "optional extras") and you should avoid using implementation specific terminology (such as "Click here").

> What smells funny to me is the part about nesting the link content into a span so that it can have disply: none; set in the css

If you do go down the route of putting *content* in *background* images and hiding real text, at least negative `text-indent` it out of sight instead of `display: none`ing it and making it invisible to screen readers.

Comment: Do you have any documentation to support the alt vs title rule? I used to use alt to describe the intended action when an img was wrapped in an anchor, but I could've sworn I read somewhere that you should use alt to describe the image content even when it's wrapped in an anchor. Also you don't get the tooltip popup on hover with an alt, it only comes with title, and I want the tooltip there for non-disabled users. Doesn't this mean I would have to duplicate the same content in both the alt and title attribs?

Comment: Try looking at the webpage in Lynx and you'll see how nonsensical a description of the image usually is (http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/alt/alt-text.html#howlers). If you want a tooltip, then you'll need to duplicate the information (but that means the image may not be informative enough).

Comment: ¿Qué? -- Thanks for the link, that was some pretty funny stuff. So do Lynx / screen readers ignore title attributes (of either images or anchor tags)?

Comment: Title attributes offer *advisory information* (which shouldn't be mandatory in order to understand the content). I don't know if Lynx provides a way to access it, some screen readers do, but there is no guarantee that the user will make use of that option (I think it is a global preference in some screen readers)