# Add random URL link to random background images

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have the following php and CSS code to generate a random background image on my homepage, every time the homepage is reloaded.

I want to add a specific URL to each of these images now as well please, so they each link to a different page. Does anyone know how I would alter this code?

Thanks

```
// random background image

add_filter('body_class','random_background_images');
function random_background_images($classes) {

//     Generate Random number from 1 to 11.  
   $background_class = 'background_' . rand(1,11);

   $classes[] = $background_class;

   return $classes;
}

/* random image background  
*/

body.background_1 .page-banner-image {
    background-image: url("/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/red_roses.jpg")!important;
}
body.background_2 .page-banner-image {
    background-image: url("/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/pink_tulips.jpg")!important;
}
body.background_3 .page-banner-image {
    background-image: url("/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/pink_roses.jpg")!important;
}

body.background_4 .page-banner-image {
    background-image: url("/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/peach_roses.jpg")!important;
}

body.background_5 .page-banner-image {
    background-image: url("/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/orange_tulips.jpg")!important;
}

body.background_6 .page-banner-image {
    background-image: url("/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/orange_lilies.jpg")!important;
}

body.background_7 .page-banner-image {
    background-image: url("/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/mixed2.jpg")!important;
}

body.background_8 .page-banner-image {
    background-image: url("/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/mixed.jpg")!important;
}

body.background_9 .page-banner-image {
    background-image: url("/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/burst_of_sunshine.jpg")!important;
}

body.background_10 .page-banner-image {
    background-image: url("/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/white_tulips.jpg")!important;
}

body.background_11 .page-banner-image {
    background-image: url("/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/red_tulips.jpg")!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action('wp_head', 'set_random_bg');

function set_random_bg(){
    if(is_home()) {
        $backgrounds = array('img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'imgN.jpg');
        $links = array('link1', 'link2', 'linkN');
        $rand_key = array_rand($backgrounds, 1);
        echo '<style> .page-banner-image {background-image: url('.$backgrounds[$rand_key].');}</style>';
        echo '<script> (function( $ ) {  $(function() { $(".page-banner-image").on("click", function(){  window.location.href="'.$links[$rand_key].'";}) });})(jQuery); </script>';

    }
}
```

`$backgrounds` can go from options, meta field or acf field.

Fixed some quotes, tested, works on my end ;)

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I tried this but I got a syntax error - syntax error, unexpected '''' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Comment: what does this mean - $backgrounds can go from options, meta field or acf field.?

Comment: At some point you can want add another background, remove old. For this you can create options page, where you can change this using wp-admin. There is many ways to do this. I prefer using AdvancedCustomFields options page. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/options-page/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't turn a background image into a link. One possible solution would be to include some JavaScript and jQuery. Below code will catch all clicks made on the page and check whether the click was on page `body` or not.

```
$('body').click(function(evt){ 
    if(evt.target === document.body){
        window.location.href="http://www.example.com";
    }
})
```

Another solution is to add the background image to some other element, that can act as a link. [Add URL link in CSS Background Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643529/add-url-link-in-css-background-image). More on this from [Wordpress forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/make-entire-background-image-a-link/).

Answer (score 0):

Store your links in an array.

```
$links_array[0] = "/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/red_roses.jpg";
$links_array[1] = "/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/pink_tulips.jpg";
.
.
.
```

Write another function to fetch the link

```
function random_background_images($classes) {

   $background_class = 'background_' . rand(1,11);

   $classes[] = $background_class;

   return $classes;
}

function getLink($background_class)
{
  $link = $links_array[substr($background_class,11)];
  return $link;
}
```

Call the function with the random background_image string as parameter e.g. `background_1` or `background_9` etc that is already generated.

```
body.background_1 .page-banner-image {
background-image: url(getLink("background_1"))!important;
}
body.background_2 .page-banner-image {
background-image: url(getLink("background_2"))!important;
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks.. how would it know which link goes with which image?

Comment: do you not want your links follow separate randomness to your images? If not you can use it for images too

Comment: no i don't want separate links.. I just want the images to be random. So if pink tulips randomly appears, I want the link to be for pink tulips... thanks

Comment: in that case I've changed the answer. Try it out. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Should the first  bit with '$links_array[1] = ' etc point to the image link, or the URL I want it to go to on click?

Comment: whatever you want here that is `background-image: url(////////HERE////////)!important;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194699/discussion-between-michelle-and-red-bottle).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with some JavaScript. Try adding following code to your HTML in a `<script>` tag:

```
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  // The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

document.querySelector('body').className += ' background_' + parseInt(getRandomArbitrary(1, 12)) + ' ';
```

Assuming here that CSS has all the background image rules specified, which you've included in your question.