# image Background not showing

Tags: html, css

HTMl STARTS HERE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap"
          rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <link
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&family=Raleway:wght@400;700&display=swap"
          rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css"
        />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css" />
        <title>Fylo | light theme page</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <header id="header-home">
          <div class="container">
            <nav class="nav-bar">
              <img src="./images/logo.svg" alt="" />
              <div class="nav-list">
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#" class="current">Features</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sing In</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </header>
        <section id="header-content">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="main">
              <div class="header-content-1">
                <h1 class="header-title">
                  All your files in one secure location accessible anywhere
                </h1>
                <p class="header-text">
                  Fylo stores your most important files in one secure location.
                  Access them wherever you need, share and collaborate with friends,
                  family, and co-workers.
                </p>
                <form action="" class="form">
                  <input
                    type="email"
                    name=""
                    id=""
                    placeholder="Enter your email"
                    class="input"
                  />
                  <button class="btn-main">Get Started</button>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div class="header-content-2">
                <img src="./images/illustration-1.svg" alt="" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section id="productive">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="main-2">
              <div class="main-context">
                <h2 class="header">Stay Productive wherever you are</h2>
                <p class="text-1">
                  Never let location be an issue whn accessing your files. Fylo has
                  you covered for all your file storage needs
                </p>
                <p class="text-2">
                  Securely share your files and folders with friends, family and
                  colleaues for live collaboration. No email attachment required
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="link"
                  >See how fylo works <img src="./images/icon-arrow.svg" alt=""
                /></a>
                <div class="card">
                  <img src="./images/icon-quotes.svg" alt="" />
                  <p class="card-text">
                    Fylo has improved our team productivity by an rder of magnitude.
                    Since making the switch our team has become a well-oiled
                    collaboration machine
                  </p>
                  <div class="avatar-info">
                    <img src="./images/avatar-testimonial.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="avatar-name">
                      <h4>Kyle Burton</h4>
                      <p>Founder& & CEO, Huddle</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="image-container">
                <img src="./images/illustration-2.svg" alt="" class="image-two" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>`
        </section>
      </body>
</html>
```

CSS STARTS HERE

```
@import "variables";

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  //   color: #fff;
  font-family: "Open sans", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
}
a {
  color: $links;
  text-decoration: none;
}
// img {
//   max-width: %;
// }
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  color: $footer;
  // text-align: center;
  // margin: 10px 0;
}
p {
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.95rem;
  // text-align: center;
  // margin: 10px 0;
  //   color: ;
}
@import "utilities";

#header-home {
  grid-area: header;
  //   display: grid;

  .nav-bar {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    // margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 2rem 1.5rem;
    position: sticky;
    // justify-content: space-between;
    ul {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
      justify-content: end;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;

      li {
        padding: 0 10px;

        a {
          font-size: 0.9rem;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          margin-right: 0.75rem;
          border-bottom: 2px transparent solid;
          padding: 2px 0;
          transition: border-color 0.2s;
          color: black;

          &:hover {
            border-color: $footer;
          }
          &.current {
            border-color: $footer;
          }
          &:last-of-type {
            margin-right: 0;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    img {
      max-width: 60%;
    }
  }
}
#header-content {
  margin-top: 90px;
  grid-area: section;
  // height: 100vh;

  .main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;

    .header-content-1 {
      // justify-content: center;
      // width: 200px;
      grid-column: 1/2;
      grid-row: 1/4;

      .header-title {
        align-self: flex-end;
        font-size: 3rem;
        // grid-column: 1/2;
      }
      .header-text {
        grid-column: 1/2;
        grid-row: 2/3;
        // width: 80%;
        margin-top: 20px;
        // padding: 0 40px;
      }
      .form {
        margin-top: 20px;
        grid-column: 1/2;
        grid-row: 2/3;

        .input {
          width: 300px;
          padding: 15px;
          border-radius: 4px;
          border: 1px solid $bg-2;

          &:focus {
            outline: none;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    .header-content-2 {
      img {
        grid-column: 2/3;
        grid-row: 1/3;
        max-width: 80%;
        justify-self: center;
        // margin-top: -10%;
        align-self: center;
      }
    }
  }
}
#productive {
  // margin-top: 200px;
  // // background-color: $bg-2;
  // position: relative;
  background-image: url(../dist/images/logo.svg);
  background-color: hsl(240, 75%, 98%);
  margin-top: 100px;
  // position: relative;
  padding: 50px 0;
  // grid-area: section;
}
```

Image background on the #productive section. i have tried a number of things and it is not responding.

Comment: You want to add a background image to whole productive section? right.

Comment: Refer this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643529/add-url-link-in-css-background-image

Comment: Yes, but nothing I try seems to be working, I have tried position absolut and relative, nothing

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to specify the background width and position. Here is an example:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(https://images7.memedroid.com/images/UPLOADED891/5c39cdc9b5921.jpeg);
  background-size: 100px;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```